# Ansible custom module inside of a role

Tags: ansible

I am trying to understand if there is a standard for sharing custom modules. Roles appear to be the way to share code and it sounds like I can include a custom module inside of a role. However, it seems like this complicates how someone would end up using the module since they need to interface through a role:

i.e. Calling a module:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - my_module:
        say_something: 'Hi'
```

i.e. Calling a module inside a role:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - include_role:
       name: my_role
    vars:
      say_something: 'Hi'
```

If we do include a module in a role, it seems like we have to write the role as an interface, which is more involved and even duplicates code to accept the variables.

So am I correct on this, or is there something I am missing? And if I am correct, is there any article or best practice on this?

Comment: I am aware of the basics around this: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#embedding-modules-and-plugins-in-roles, but my question is more around the variables passed to the role to be passed to the module.

Answer (score 1):

Create `library` directory where your `playbook` reside and place your custom module `.py` file inside the `library` directory, then you can use it inside your playbook.

Here is the directory structure:

```
playbook.yml
[library]
  |_ your_custom_moudle_1.py
  |_ your_custom_moudle_2.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I guess my question is more around the variables passed to a module. This is the piece I am trying to understand if the module gets pulled into a role. Like my example shows, passing the variables to the module is pretty straight-forward and easy to understand, but when you wrap it into a role that is where I get lost; I feel like the role in this case needs to be developed as an interface to the module, which to me would be duplicate code in a sense to pass the variables from the role to the module.

Answer (score 0):

### So from your Example

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - include_role:
       name: my_role
    vars:
      say_something: 'Hi'



Now in your role, you can use above var as

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - my_module:
        say_something: "{{ say_something }}"

You can have different names for variable as well

- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - include_role:
       name: my_role
    vars:
      say_something_1: 'Hi'



- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - my_module:
        say_something: "{{ say_something_1 }}"
```

Now for sharing things, You can look into collections
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html